# Suppose $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \frac{3(4-2x-y)}{16}$ for $x>0$, $y>0$ and $2x+y<4$. Find $P(Y>2\mid X=1/2)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

Suppose $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \frac{3(4-2x-y)}{16}$ for $x>0$, $y>0$ and $2x+y<4$.

Find $P(Y>2\mid X=1/2).$

Not sure if I have the correct solution. Would someone let me know if this makes sense? I am not sure about the limits of integration on the two integrals.

Solution: 
First, find the marginal of $X$. 
$$f_X(x)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{X,Y}(x,y) \, dy=\frac{3}{16}\int_0^{4-2x}(4-2x-y) \, dy =\frac{3}{16}(2x^2-8x+8)$$
So we have that  $$f_{Y\mid X}(y\mid x) = \frac{\frac{3}{16}(4-2x-y)}{\frac{3}{16}(2x^2-8x+8)}.$$

Simplifying and substituting $x=1/2$, we have $$f(Y=y\mid x=1/2)=\frac{2}{9}(3-y).$$

So

$$P(Y>2\mid X=1/2)=\frac{2}{9} \int_2^3 (3-y) \, dy=\frac{1}{9}$$

Comment: Oh yes. I forgot to cancel the 3/16 in the denominator. I think it works now.

Comment: You final answer now agrees with mine.